# VSFTPD does not work with SSL

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, ftp, vsftpd

I am trying to enable ssl on my vsftpd server, it works without SSL, but when I try to install this certificate it gives me the following error: `Process: 1314 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf (code=exited, status=2)` when I try to restart the service

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
local_root=/var/www
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
hide_ids=YES

#virutal user settings
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd_user_conf
guest_enable=YES
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
nopriv_user=vsftpd
guest_username=vsftpd

## SSL

ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1_1=YES
ssl_tlsv1_2=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=YES
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
```

I generated the SSL cert using: `sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem -out /etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem`

**EDIT #1**
I changed the SSL part of the configuration to

```
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/vsftpd.crt
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.key
ssl_enable=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
```

The service can now start, but my filezilla log shows:

```
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 (vsFTPd 3.0.5)
Command:    AUTH TLS
Response:   504 Command not implemented for that parameter
Command:    AUTH SSL
Response:   504 Command not implemented for that parameter
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Command:    USER runner
Response:   530 Non-anonymous sessions must use encryption.
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Comment: Are you sure the PEM file have inside the private key and certificate?

Comment: check the log files of the server for detailed error messages

Comment: @SteffenUllrich even with logging enabled it does not log anything to the file, how can I debug this? thanks

Comment: @RomeoNinov yeah bot the keys are inside, the private key comes first

Comment: @YaRmgl, try to separate them (private and certificate) and check again

Comment: @RomeoNinov followed this tutorial: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/configure-vsftpd-ssl/ to set an ssl key, still gives me an error status 2 with no specific error message

Answer (score 0):

I switched to implicit SSL, and only enabled TLSv1 and commented out the others, here is my full config:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
local_root=/var/www
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
hide_ids=YES

#virutal user settings
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd_user_conf
guest_enable=YES
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
nopriv_user=vsftpd
guest_username=vsftpd

## logs
vsftpd_log_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log

## SSL

rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/vsftpd.crt
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.key

ssl_enable=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
implicit_ssl=YES
listen_port=990
```